# Make VF Page Commandlink target variable

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, controller-extension

I have a VF link on a page which creates a new record. It's embedded on a page layout. My problem is that I would like errors to show in the embedded section without redirecting, but if it's successful, I would like the page to redirect to the new record. Is there is way to say if the page has errors, target = '_self' else target = '_top'?

Something like:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!autoRun}" value="Create Dog Record" target="{!pgTarget}"/>
```

This doesn't work because it doesn't update the pgTarget part.

Comment: Did my ans solve your purpose? If so, then close the ques

Answer (score 1):

You can use `oncomplete` function rather than using `target` as below:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!autoRun}" value="Create Dog Record" oncomplete="doRedirect('{!pgTarget}')"/>

<script>
function doRedirect(param){
    if(param == '_top'){
        window.open('<pageURL>',param);
    }   
}
</script>
```

It has been assumed that you will assign correct `pgTarget` inside the controller based on successful or error condition.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had found a different work around using this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552514/visualforce-page-embedded-in-a-detail-page-that-needs-to-redirect-to-other-page
I will however try your answer when I have time later to see if it works out and mark it as the answer if it functions as expected.